# Finding conditional probability P[A|B,C] when B and C are related

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Consider an apple tee. If the weather is good, it produces $x$ apples with probability $p(x|g)$. If the weather is bad, you get $x$ apples with probability $p(x|b)$. Here, g and b stand for good and bad respectively.

Out of the $x$ apples, if the weather is good, $y$ apples are sweet and $x-y$ apples are not sweet. $y$ happens with probability $q(y|x,g)$. Similarly, if the weather is bad, $y$ follows a pmf $q(y|x,b)$.

What I want to find is the probability of the good weather when I found $y$ sweet apples among $x$ apples, i.e., $P[g|x,y]$.

How do I compute this conditional probability that depends on two variables that one is somehow related to the other?

Comment: First, see [Bayes Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).  This problem which will have a computation in the form of $$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}}.$$  Here, $D$ will represent the sum of the probabilities of two events: Event-1 and Event-2.  Event-1 represents the probability of : $x$ apples, given good weather times $y$ apples given $x$ apples in good weather.  Event-2 represents the analogous bad weather scenario.  The numerator, $N$, will only deal with Event-1.

Comment: Drawing a tree diagram makes things simpler, at least for me.  The 1st pair of branches for good and bad weather; the 2nd pair of branches for sweet and non-sweet apples.